# Get Touching components using their AABB bounding box C#

Tags: c#, cad, kdtree, octree

I have a problem statement.

1. I have 1000 3d components in a cad assembly.
2. For all 1000 components I have 3d AABB bounding box.

I want to get the pair of components that are touching each other in the most efficient way.

[You can see the image for more reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNZ2M.png)

Currently, we are looping through all components in for loop and doing the distance computation. It is proving to be time-consuming.

I would like to optimize the current solution. Preferably using C#, Octtree, KD tree, etc.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: What does "touching" mean, exactly?

Comment: Touching: If two components are at zero distance

Comment: I'm not sure that helps. Show the code for your distance calculation

Comment: @CaiusJard I am using a distance API using cad API, in this case Autodesk Inventor API.